# Downloading web content in .Net console application using HttpClient

Tags: .net, web-scraping, download, dotnet-httpclient

So I'm trying to scrap a web page (that I do not have access to behind the scenes/can't control) to extract links from it in a .Net 6 console application. I'm using HttpClient to downloading the web page to memory in a text file and then go through and pull the links out of it. I then iterate through the links and download their respective files to memory using HttpClient again. What's odd is that I get a 404 server error intermittently on my home network but when I run this at a coffee shop with significantly faster internet it didn't fail. I haven't been able to find anything about this online and I'm wondering if it's my code or the network, and if there's anything I can do about it. Any help would be appreciated, code snippets below.

Note: For saving straight to memory I've tried two different ways of downloading. The active one here came from https://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/efficiently-streaming-large-http-responses-with-httpclient and the commented out one is what we made initially.

The downloader class along with it's method to download assets from the passed in url

```
public class Downloader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Downloader class's HttpClient instance
    /// </summary>
    private HttpClient client { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Downloader class that provides methods for downloading web pages and files from internet based resources.
    /// </summary>
    public Downloader()
    {   
        this.client = new HttpClient();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to assist in downloading web pages and files to local memory
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A string containing the file name of the downloaded web asset
    /// </returns>
    public async Task<string> GetWebAsset(string url)
    {
        // File name is the end of the url or temp.txt
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(url) != string.Empty ? Path.GetFileName(url) : "temp.txt";

        // Paths can contain ?ver=xyz after their extension, remove additional params
        if (fileName.Contains("?")) {
            string[] fileNameParts = fileName.Split("?");
            fileName = fileNameParts[0];
        }

        string newFileName = fileName;

        // Make sure the current file name doesn't exist in memory, append a number to it if it does
        int i = 0;
        while(File.Exists(newFileName))
        {
            newFileName = fileName;
            i++;
            string[] fileNameParts = fileName.Split(".");
            newFileName = fileNameParts[0] + i.ToString() + "." + fileNameParts[1];
        }

        fileName = newFileName;

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await this.client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
        using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            using (Stream fileToWriteTo = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(fileToWriteTo);
            }
        }

        // using var downloadStream = await this.client.GetStreamAsync(url);
        // using var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);

        // await downloadStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);

        return fileName;
    }
```

Example call

```
Downloader dl = new Downloader();
string google = await dl.GetWebAsset("https://www.google.com/");
```

Sometimes it works, other times I end up with this.

MANAGEMENT.zip

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, tried different ways of downloading to memory, tried different urls, tried different internet connections. I would expect to get a file with the name of the link or a temp.txt that contains the contents of the file we downloaded. The links all work in chrome and in postman.